# Azure Notification Hubs - GetNotificationOutcomeDetailAsync PnsErrorDetailsUri always NULL

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-notificationhub

I yesterday upgraded our Azure Notification Hub (ANH) from Free to Standard.
When we call `NotificationHubClient.GetNotificationOutcomeDtailsAsync` for a valid `NotificationId` we get a good `NotificationDetails` structure, except that the `PnsErrorDetailsUri` property is always null.

However if I use the [SendRestExample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/dotnet/SendRestExample) against the same ANH I am able to get a valid `contrainerUri` (e.g. the sample's REST call to `https://<mynamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<My Namespace>/feedbackcontrain?api-version=2015-04`) which the SendRestExample code is able to then GET and traverse.

Is there a bug in the `NotificationHubClient.GetNotificationOutcomeDetailsAsync` code such that it does not ever fill in the `PnsErrorDetailsUri` property?  Do I need to wait 24-hours before  `NotificationHubClient.GetNotificationOutcomeDetailsAsync` will work like the raw REST calls work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [Retrieve platform notification system error details with Azure Notification Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/retrieve-platform-notification-system-error-details-with-azure-notification-hubs/) for more details and note that the URI will be `null` when there's no error from PNSes.